# VS 2017 c# interactive is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-interactive

I'm trying to use VS C# Interactive on a project (dll output) which is referencing com x86 references. I'm selecting the project and right click on "Initialize Interactive with Project". When then I try to execute my code. I get a count not load file or assembly .... or one if its dependencies is not a valid Win32 application. Is C# Interactive limited to Any CPU project?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it runs in 64-bit mode. Csi.exe is also a 64-bit app. No options I see to change this.  Hacking csi.exe with corflags.exe did not work either, it invalidated the strong name and made assembly loads fail.  Odd btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, I changed the plateform target of my project (in that case a dll which is referenced by different solution) and I was able to get C# Interactive working. It made me evaluate carrefully the difference between platform target of referenced assembly (where c# interactive is valuable as the output cannot be executed) vs applications where testing can be done in inline editing in debug. It was indeed a nice exercise.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to reset the execution engine of the interactive window using `#reset 32` for 32-bit mode and `#reset 64` for 64-bit mode.
Tested with VS 2017 Enterprise version 15.8.6